# apply filter only one route on api platform 2.7

Tags: filter, api-platform.com

I try to apply a filter on one route specifically. It's worked on api platform 2.6 but not anymore since we migrated to 2.7 with php8 annotation. Do you know if we can still do this ?

ex:

my service.yaml

```
    entity.search_filter:
    parent: 'api_platform.doctrine.orm.search_filter'
    arguments: [ { plateNumber: "partial" } ]
    tags: [ 'api_platform.filter' ]
```

my entity.php

```
#[ApiResource(
shortName: 'entity',
operations: [
    new GetCollection(
        uriTemplate: '/entities',
        normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['entity:full:read']],
        security: 'is_granted(\'ROLE_ENTITY_READ\')',
        filters: ['entity.search_filter']
    ),
```